# Get a random string from a table, but not more than once

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how i can get random strings out of a table, including 10 words. I'm creating the game hangman, but i don't want one word twice. The game shall go on until 5 words are picked.

Are there any good solutions? This is the randomizing method for my table as it is now.

```
private String wordList[] = { "String1", "String2", ..... }
public void getRandomWord(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int r = generator.nextInt(9);
    activeWord = wordList[r];
}
```

I tried getting this to work, but no luck:

```
ArrayList<String> usedWords= new ArrayList<String>();
public void getRandomWord(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    int r = generator.nextInt(9);
    if(addWord(wordList[r])){
        activeWord= wordList[r];
    }
}

private boolean addWord(String word) {
    for(String v : usedWords){
        if(!v.equals(word)){
            usedWords.add(word);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            getRandomWord();
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

I think i've made an iteration, but i'm guessing thats not nessasary.

I've been thinking about having a string table with boolean value. So if the value of the word is true, ill grab it, if its not, ill keep going until i find a word.

I might use a while loop for that?

Comment: Shuffle it in advance, then simply select in order. No lookups, no booleans, no collisions. Look into algorithms such as Fisher-Yates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make wordList an ArrayList you can remove the word from the list each time you use it. That way the list of possible values shrinks and there is no risk of picking a word twice.

Comment: I like the idea of this one. This is an android app. Is this still doable if i'm going to add these words in an string value?

Comment: Yes, I believe ArrayList exists on the android platform.